# Grails - No Session if Additional Header is Present

Tags: grails, mobile, groovy, session-state

What is the best way to configure Grails so that sessions are not created for requests that come in with an additional specific HTTP header? These will be API requests coming in from mobile devices.

Would this save much resources if 75% of my users will be mobile?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Grails really puts a lot into your session on creation, if anything at all. So, if your app doesn't put anything sizeable into the session, your gain is marginal.